# Inter-process communication: named pipes or status files

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm building a tool that consists of a Webservice that will run commandline tools at specific times. On average there will be running 15-20 CL tools at the same time. Every CL tool runs no longer than about 0,5-1 minute on average. The webservice needs to be able to check each CL's status every 2-3 seconds or so.

I've got some advice about how to do this; named pipes looks likes the best "technical" solution. However I'm wondering if communicating with simple very small text "status" files would be a better, less complicated and less error-risk, way. I prefer the solution that is the most resource friendly.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Named pipes would be better. You might run into access problems with the two processes trying to access the small text file at once.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar before and here's what I did.

I start the command line process by setting `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` to `true`. Then I start listening to the command line process' output by doing:

```
process.OutputDataReceived += dataReceivedEventHandler;
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Then in my `dataReceivedEventHandler`, I parse `DataReceivedEventArgs.Data` to see if my console application sent me a "message" that begins with a tag that I created (ex: "[ServerProgress]10").

So basically, the applications are communicating through the console output. Not elegant, but it did the job for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, status checks - not a huge footprint there, I'd go with named pipes any day. Using memory >> using HDD here.